# Elsevier Journal waiting time after review process

Tags: publications, paper-submission, elsevier

I have submitted a revised manuscript that has been "under review" again for the past 7 months. After a long wait, I have written a polite email to editor inquiring about a long delay in the revised review once I got positive reviews and minor corrections. It has been almost 3 weeks the Editor did not even replied to my email and still the status is the same. Any suggestions How long I should wait? or is it normal a practice by PHYSICA A journal of Elsevier?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about  PHYSICA A (I am from another field).
You may try to write to Elsvier Support: https://service.elsevier.com/app/contact/supporthub/publishing/
Maybe they can somehow push the things.